# How can made multiple user login at same time in same browser in django project

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project in which i want to implement chat.I have write code for chat but i am facing a problem at same time i cant login two or more user .How can i use multiple login for chat
My code for chat is
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Chat(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```

**views.py**

```
def Login(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '/home/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account is not active at the moment.")
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
    return render(request, "alpha/login.html", {'next': next})

def Logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

def Home(request):
    c = Chat.objects.all()
    return render(request, "alpha/home.html", {'home': 'active', 'chat': c})

def Post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        msg = request.POST.get('msgbox', None)
        c = Chat(user=request.user, message=msg)
        if msg != '':
            c.save()
        return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.user.username })
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Request must be POST.')

def Messages(request):
    c = Chat.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'alpha/messages.html', {'chat': c})
```

Comment: This is not django question nor is it a python question. If you want two users to login at the same time to the dev server user two different browsers use incognito mode to make it 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you only want to use it for testing purposes. If that is the case, I suggest you use the browsers' **"Incognito Mode"**, and that way you can have two sessions. E.g.: in Chrome, you can activate an incognito window (which starts a separate session from your main browser window) by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+N`. You can read more about it at [Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en). Of course, there is an equivalent for it for Edge, Firefox, etc.

Alternatively, you can also use multiple browser - one Chrome, one Microsoft Edge, and one Firefox and in each log in with a different user