# How does multiple user types logging in & out work in a live environment? [Django]

Tags: django, authentication, session, cookies

I have a web app that has two different user types, Nurses and Doctors, and they can both log in and out. I opened two tabs and logged in as a Nurse in one tab and as a Doctor in the other. However, when I log out of either one of those tabs, the other will be automatically logged out as well.

I have read this link [How can made multiple user login at same time in same browser in django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133204/how-can-made-multiple-user-login-at-same-time-in-same-browser-in-django-project) and understand why this happens. I know that I can work around it by logging in from different web browsers and by using Incognito mode. However, how do I code it such that in a live environment, users can actually logout without logging other users out?

Comment: in a live environment, nobody's gonna log in that way. It's gonna be a doctor or a Nurse,  one possibility.  you can use multiple browsers or Incognito mode. but it's only for testing/development purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by in a live environment, nobody's gonna log in that way? In a live environment, a doctor can log in while a nurse is already logged in right? So if the nurse then logs out, the doctor will still get logged out too.

Comment: is it fine if I left my account logged in as a Doctor and any nurse can open up without my concern? one system for all? Sure? They both have separate systems to do their stuff. If you're considering one System for all Then I don't think that there is such a way except multiple Browsers